# Stop Async Time Delay inside for each loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, foreach, datagridview

I have datagrid view that show data from MySQL database. I want to show the data grouped by customer and changed every 10 seconds. heres example of my database

| Order | Customer | Payment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Cust1 | Card |
| 02 | Cust2 | Cash |
| 03 | Cust2 | Cash |
| 04 | Cust1 | Card |
| 05 | Cust1 | Card |
| 06 | Cust2 | Card |

I have try distinct the customer from the table and set it to datatable

```
Async Sub dgvquery()
   conn.Open()
   da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM tbtransaction", conn)
   Dim dtcust As New DataTable
   da.Fill(dtcust)
   conn.Close()

   For Each drowcust As DataRow In dtcust.Rows
       dgvtransaction.Rows.Clear()
       Dim dim cust As String
       cust = drowcust.Item("Customer")

       conn.Open()
       da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from tbtransaction WHERE Customer = '" & cust & "' AND Payment = '" & cbpayment.text & "'", conn)
       ds = New DataSet
       da.Fill(ds)
       dgvtransaction.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
       conn.Close()
   Next
   Await Task.Delay(10000)
End Sub
```

that code working fine but the problem is when is change the combobox of payment method the old loop still running and the datagridview showing the old loop and then the changed to current loop until the old loop is finished. how do I stop the old loop when combobox value is changed

Answer (score 0):

Start by removing the loop: a simple query grouped by customer should do the trick:

```
Async Sub dgvquery()
    conn.Open()
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT  Customer, Order, Payment from tbtransaction GROUP BY Customer, Order, Payment HAVING Payment = '" & cbpayment.text & "'", conn)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds)
    dgvtransaction.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    conn.Close()
    Await Task.Delay(10000)
End Sub
```